# Calculating average with minimum and maximum

Tags: maxima-minima, average

Maybe it's a simple question but I have not any idea for that at the moment!

How we can calculate average value for **N** samples with having only the **minimum** and **maximum** values?

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Compare with $0,1,8$ and $0,7,8$.

---

In fact, the average can be anywhere in

$$\left[\frac{(n-1)\min+\max}n,\frac{\min+(n-1)\max}n\right],$$

and if the distribution is skewed, the average of the minimum and maximum will be biased.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can't. If you have two samples of numbers, let's say 
$$\{0,2,3,1,1,1,8\}\quad \text{and} \quad \{0,7,7,6,4,8,8\}$$
the average of these samples will be different, but they have the same maximum and minimum values. If you're only given the maximum and minimum, you could make a **guess** that the average is $\frac{\text{max}+\text{min}}{2}$, but it's probably not a good guess.